# how to initialize a subrange of array of modules

Tags: omnet++

I want to initialize a parameter in `omnetpp.ini` file. The parameter is in form of an array of a certain module type. I want half of the instances have a certain amount and the other half another amount. For example the array is `basestation[100]`. I want something like:

```
basestation[0-49].mobility.initialX = 10

basestation[50-99].mobility.initialX = 40
```

Is there an easy way to do it? (instead of doing all instances one by one!!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [OMNeT++ User Manual's section 9.3.1 ("Using Wildcard Patterns")](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec:ch-config-sim:wildcards) covers numeric ranges.

Applying this to your example, the following will work:

```
basestation[0..49].mobility.initialX = 10
basestation[50..99].mobility.initialX = 40
```

Note that you can also omit the start or end of the range.